# how can I change the default name of safari “print to pdf” documents?

Tags: safari

Saving prints of particular website to track changes.  Would like to change the name of the saved pdf file to reflect time*date when I did the pdf print instead of just the webpage name.  (e.g. XXDashboard-2017-10-12-13-02 )
TIA

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could automate the job using an Automator script.
Automator is nbuilt right into Mac OSX, so you don't have to install anything.

Here is a tutorial on how to automate some tasks:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/58986/automator-for-mac-tutorial-and-examples